# Recovery of a broken Hard Disk's filesystem using ddrescue and testdisk

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, hard-disk, dd, data-recovery

After working on a partially rescued partition, I was told to use `ddrescue` to save a failing external hard drive and then apply `testdisk` over it to complete the rescue operation. Although the drive has been almost fully saved onto a second one (due to my hasty removal during particularly nasty clicking sounds and subsequent insertion in a Windows partition), testdisk appears to still see the new drive as "defective". More specifically, `Quick Search` only returns a handful of folders and files, while the log specifically mentions a `Bad Relative Sector`. I was wondering what further steps should I take as I've been told that the possibilities that I have right now are:

1. Redoing the ddrescue attempt, letting it fully finish and hopefully having testdisk recreate the filesystem;
2. Using Photorec on the rescued drive and hoping to grab as many items from it as possible;
3. Using other tools to recover my data.
   Additionally, I've been told to ask for a more detailed solution on https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12307 as well.

The following is an excerpt of the log for the ddrescue operation (full log is too large and can be found here https://pastebin.com/mCi0DgEi ):

```
Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
# Command line: ddrescue -f /dev/sdc /dev/sdb /home/marco/Desktop/log1.log

# Start time:   2023-03-28 23:06:35
# Current time: 2023-04-03 17:29:58
# Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status
0xC6DC9200     /
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x586DF000  +
0x586DF000  0x0000D000  -
0x586EC000  0x67F48000  +
0xC0634000  0x00720000  -
0xC0D54000  0x00034000  +
0xC0D88000  0x00001000  -
0xC0D89000  0x00009000  +
0xC0D92000  0x00001000  -
0xC0D93000  0x0002B000  +
0xC0DBE000  0x00008000  -
0xC0DC6000  0x00001000  +
0xC0DC7000  0x00001000  -
0xC0DC8000  0x00ABC000  +
0xC1884000  0x00001000  -
0xC1885000  0x0000A000  +
0xC188F000  0x00001000  -
0xC1890000  0x002CA000  +
0xC1B5A000  0x00001000  -
0xC1B5B000  0x005FF000  +
0xC215A000  0x00001000  -
......................
0xAAC1E54200  0x00002C00  /
0xAAC1E56E00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC1E57000  0x003B1000  +
0xAAC2208000  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2208200  0x00000C00  /
0xAAC2208E00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2209000  0x00317000  +
0xAAC2520000  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2520200  0x00000C00  /
0xAAC2520E00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2521000  0x0001C000  +
0xAAC253D000  0x00000200  -
0xAAC253D200  0x00000C00  /
0xAAC253DE00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC253E000  0x00077000  +
0xAAC25B5000  0x00000200  -
0xAAC25B5200  0x00003C00  /
0xAAC25B8E00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC25B9000  0x0008F000  +
0xAAC2648000  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2648200  0x00000C00  /
0xAAC2648E00  0x00000200  -
0xAAC2649000  0x11CDF4CE000  +
0x1C7A1B17000  0x00000200  -
0x1C7A1B17200  0x00000C00  /
0x1C7A1B17E00  0x00000200  -
0x1C7A1B18000  0x00099000  +
0x1C7A1BB1000  0x00000200  -
0x1C7A1BB1200  0x00000C00  /
0x1C7A1BB1E00  0x00000200  -
0x1C7A1BB2000  0x2CD9ED000  +
0x1CA6F59F000  0x00000200  -
0x1CA6F59F200  0x00000C00  /
0x1CA6F59FE00  0x00000200  -
0x1CA6F5A0000  0x751B76000  +`
```

In addition, here's the partial output of testdisk:

`   Mon Apr  3 22:54:40 2023
Command line: TestDisk /log /debug

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 4.15.0-142-generic (#146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021) x86_64
Compiler: GCC 5.3
ext2fs lib: 1.42.13, ntfs lib: libntfs-3g, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none, curses lib: ncurses 6.0
/dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sda: size       625142448 sectors
/dev/sda: user_max   625142448 sectors
/dev/sda: native_max 625142448 sectors
Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/sda - 320 GB / 298 GiB - CHS 38913 255 63, sector size=512 - WDC WD3200BPVT-80JJ5T0, S/N:WD-WXU1EA1LJZPV, FW:01.01A01
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63, sector size=512 - TOSHIBA EXTERNAL_USB

Partition table type (auto): Intel
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - TOSHIBA EXTERNAL_USB
Partition table type: Intel

Analyse Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
Geometry from i386 MBR: head=255 sector=63
BAD_RS LBA=2048 63
NTFS at 0/32/33
Current partition structure:
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 243201  48 31 3907025072

Bad relative sector.
Record 5617 has wrong SeqNo (1 <> 2)

search_part()
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
NTFS at 0/32/33
filesystem size           3907025072
sectors_per_cluster       8
mft_lcn                   786432
mftmirr_lcn               2
clusters_per_mft_record   -10
clusters_per_index_record 1
     HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 243201  48 31 3907025072
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1863 GiB

Results
   * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 243201  78 13 3907026944
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1863 GiB

Hint for advanced users. dmsetup may be used if you prefer to avoid to rewrite the partition table for the moment:
echo "0 3907026944 linear /dev/sdb 2048" | dmsetup create test0
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
NTFS Volume is dirty.


dir_partition inode=5
   * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 243201  78 13 3907026944
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1863 GiB
ntfs_readdir failed for cluster 5: Input/output error
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0  3-Apr-2023 17:45 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0  3-Apr-2023 17:45 ..
    4335 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0  7-Mar-2016 07:57 $RECYCLE.BIN
  530569 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 29-Mar-2016 16:25 Folder1
  531255 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Feb-2016 16:00 Folder2
  524569 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Feb-2016 15:54 Folder3
 1064063 -r--r--r--     0      0      3538  4-Mar-2016 23:54 list.txt

interface_write()
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 243201  78 13 3907026944
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
::: several similar lines :::
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x93d9b08c  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 59825  usa_count: 16722: Invalid argument
Using locale 'LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8'.`
```

The steps I followed to get this far are summarized in here https://archive.is/j66F9
Many thanks to user [dodrg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21390763/dodrg) for having been extremely patient with me in the original question.

Comment: Which one, the moderators deleted both of them, I had remade the question with more information as I finished part of the steps (and the scope of the original problem basically required a rewrite of the question anyhow).

Comment: ddrescue works best if you let it write to a new file (not a block device). This is to guarantee that any gaps are binary zero and not any old data on the HDD. fsck, testdisk and other recovery tools work best if you use snapshots / copy-on-write overlays. Otherwise, you can not revert any changes these tools make in your copy. Filling gaps in the copy after it has already been changed, might not be too helpful anymore. Any recovery attempts that involve changing on-disk data, are mostly one-shots: they are either successful, or they cause even more damage... you get lucky, or not.

Comment: I see. The problem with the new file approach is that the entire hard disk is 2TBs large and I don't have any storage device larger than that. I'll keep what you said in mind though.

Comment: I'm not surprised they deleted them if you posted them to StackOverflow. Its FAQ says, "_Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers,_" so your question would have been off-topic there. But it is on-topic here so good luck

Comment: I assumed that discussions on ddrescue would be fair game, plus it was left up for quite a long time, but I guess it just didn't have enough traction to warrant deletion the first time around.

Comment: Double posting:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=37173#p37173

Comment: Added onto the main question body

Comment: Update: I've completed the second pass, no difference in log file compared to the original one. Should I just attempt to use Photorec? Testdisk is not giving me any new results.

Answer (score 1):

> Redoing the ddrescue attempt, letting it fully finish and hopefully having testdisk recreate the filesystem

Provided you still have the intermediate log file that `ddrescue` produces you can restart the recovery process and it will attempt to continue from where it left off. However if you have already changed the target image in any way then this would significantly reduce your chances of continuing and you should consider restarting over (with a new log file) to a new image.

Note that `ddrescue` doesn't require the target to be a device - a file on a sufficiently large partition is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Yeah, I've tried completing the rescue attempt using the `-C` directive. It'll take a few more hours due to the bad sectors, but I'll give you a sitrep with a new log file once it's done. Hopefully, Testdisk will allow me to see a bit more this time.